# Button with a glyphicon in the middle and number on the top left corner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a button like the number pad key but with a number in the left corner. It supose to have a glyphicon in the center, a text bellow that and a small number on the left top corner.
I can't put the number in the top left corner he always stand on the left of the glyphicon.

```css
.btn-default{
    height: 8vh; 
        font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
}

.txt{
     font-size: 8px;
     color:blue;  
     right:0;
     top:0;
}
```

```html
   <button type="button" id="buttonPlay" class="btn btn-default btn-lg text-center" ng-click="vid.playVideo()">
                 <span class="txt" > 8 </span>
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><br>Play
                <!-- <span class="tooltiptext">Play</span>-->
        </button>
```

I already try margin and right: 0 and top:0 but nothing seems to work, any help!?

Comment: `top` and `right` have no effect if the element isn’t `position`ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element will work with **positions**. Giving `position:relative` to `button` and `position:absolute` to the `txt` wil do the trick.

> Here is the working code of what you need:

```css
.btn-default{
   
        font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      position:relative;
}

.txt{
     font-size: 12px;
     color:blue;  
     left:10px;
     top:0;
     position:absolute;
     color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="buttonPlay" class="btn btn-default btn-lg text-center" ng-click="vid.playVideo()">
                 <span class="txt" > 8 </span>
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><br>Play
                <!-- <span class="tooltiptext">Play</span>-->
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use float left to left item and float right to right item and use padding on button to apply alignment on elements of button.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide position to button and span element like this :

```css
   button {
position:relative;
}
button span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

```html
   <button type="button" id="buttonPlay" class="btn btn-default btn-lg text-center" ng-click="vid.playVideo()">
                 <span class="txt" > 8 </span>
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><br>Play
                <!-- <span class="tooltiptext">Play</span>-->
        </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the **button** `position:relative` and the **span** `position:absolute`